# Iterating through a range in both directions

Tags: javascript, arrays, shorthand

There is a very common and easy task of looped iteration through some range in both directions:

```js
var currentIndex = 0;
var range = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

function getNextItem(direction) {
    currentIndex += direction;
    if (currentIndex >= range.length) { currentIndex = 0; }
    if (currentIndex < 0) { currentIndex = range.length-1; }

    return range[currentIndex];
}        
// get next "right" item
console.log(getNextItem(1));

// get next "left" item
console.log(getNextItem(-1));
```

The code above works perfectly, but I spent about an hour trying to get rid of double `if` check.

Is there any way to solve if without if? Sort of one-liner maybe?

Comment: Are you sure it works perfectly, `getNextItem(-1);` gives `undefined`?

Comment: You can also use ternary operator for that.

Comment: Btw, it should rather be an `if … else if` not a double `if`

Comment: @Bergi should it? Why?

Comment: @DenisO. it will try to check both `if` condition on each iteration, whereas with `else .. if` it won't

Comment: @DenisO. Because they are exclusive, you would either hit the end or the start of your array, but not both, and you would never want both statement to be executed. Of course, that can't happen given how the code is currently written, but using an `else` makes the intention clear, skips one unnecessary check, and makes mistakes cause less confusing results.

Comment: Btw, also consider what your function should do when being called on an empty array.

Comment: @Bergi, agree :) but this wasn't a production ready code, just an illustration of what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To turn the two `if`s into one unconditional statement, you can add the `range.length` to the `currentIndex` and then use modulo:

```js
var currentIndex = 0;
var range = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

function getNextItem(direction) {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + direction + range.length) % range.length;
    return range[currentIndex];
}

// get next "right" item
console.log(getNextItem(1));
console.log(getNextItem(1));

// get next "left" item
console.log(getNextItem(-1));
console.log(getNextItem(-1));
console.log(getNextItem(-1));

console.log(getNextItem(4));
console.log(getNextItem(1));
console.log(getNextItem(1));
console.log(getNextItem(1));
```